# Calling a specific row in single.php wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to call a single row in each wordpress post. I was thinking that the best way to go around this is to insert a piece of code in the `single.php` file where I call via the post id:

```
<?php 

$result  = "SELECT post_date FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = get_the_ID()";
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['post_date'];

?>
```

However this doesn't seem to work. Can anyone shed some light on why this isn't working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress offers a nice database abstraction layer to remove your need to read the posts table directly. It's apparent from your use of get_the_ID() that you're working with the "current" post or page in your code.  So, guess what? That row of the posts table has already been loaded by WordPress. Try something like this to retrieve it.

```
 $post = get_post();
 echo $post->post_date;
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post for more information.

Comment: All that does is echo this text:  post_date; ?>

Comment: Actually all it needed was this statement:    <?php echo $post->url; ?>

THanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `get_the_ID()` in wordpress is a PHP function, not a SQL function. So try:

```
$result  = "SELECT post_date FROM wp_posts WHERE ID = ".intval(get_the_ID());
```

*`intval` force the use of a number, and avoid the SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This made no difference though.

Comment: What is the return value for `get_the_ID()` function? Try `var_dump` it.

Comment: you lost me... Shouldn't it simply return the post id

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
global $post;
// $ids is an array with the required id's
$ids = array(1,2,24,234,2342);
$args = array(
    'include'          => $ids,
);

$myposts = get_posts($args);
//You always need $post, because setup_postdata assings eveyrhing to post...
//thats a Wordpres...way of things...
foreach($myposts as $post): setup_postdata($post):
    the_time('F jS, Y');
//Don't forget to reset postdata
wp_reset_postdata();
endofreach;
```